# Samba installation on read-only system

Tags: linux, debian, samba, read-only

I couldn't find anything usefull on web.

Here is the story. I'm trying to install Samba (version 4.5.12) on Debian (Raspbian, but it doesn't matter). Debian is installed on read-only filesystem. Installation is ok, but samba is not launching on RO-mode (read-only). I was trying to make symbolic links of necessary data (`/var/lib/samba files`) on external HDD (which is read-write), but i've got an error at Samba's start - systemctl failed to start smdb.service. In `systemctl status` was nothing interesting. But in `samba/log.` I've found that:

```
[2018/04/01 17:11:55.333301,  0] ../lib/util/util.c:270(directory_create_or_exist_strict)
  directory /var/lib/samba/private/msg.sock isn't a directory
[2018/04/01 17:12:35.116576,  0] ../lib/util/util.c:270(directory_create_or_exist_strict)
  directory /var/lib/samba/private/msg.sock isn't a directory
[2018/04/01 17:42:24.843043,  0] ../lib/util/util.c:216(directory_create_or_exist)
  mkdir failed on directory /var/lib/samba/private/msg.sock: Read-only file system
[2018/04/01 18:04:41.824892,  0] ../lib/util/util.c:216(directory_create_or_exist)
  mkdir failed on directory /var/lib/samba/private/msg.sock: No such file or directory
```

Googling helped me find out, that the `directory_create_or_exist_strict` function in Samba source code checks for directories (in my case for `/var/lib/samba/private/msg.sock`) to be real.

Is there any linux-way solution? Should I re-write the `directory_create_or_exist_strict` function or make absolute path for `msg.sock` directory on external HDD? Or there is any other way to mirror that folder to external HDD? Please, share some tip-offs with me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that you are using a softlink to redirect the samba var folder to the other disk.
A softlink behaves somewhat differently than a real folder and could be not acceptable to the samba socket creation code.

What I would do in a setup like yours is put the entire /var filesystem on the other disk (or as a tmpfs) and simply mount it at boot-time.
Or, if you don't wan to go all the way, just create a tmpfs filesystem at boot and mount that at /var/lib/samba.

A mount-point should be OK. Otherwise no Linux system would ever be able to put /var on a different filesystem.

Comment: Bind-mounting existing tmpfs (to not spawn gazillions tmpfs instance) to `/var/lib/samba/private/msg.sock` indeed worked, thanks.